# MSM - Use specific site if logged in

Tags: members, multi-site-manager

First time using MSM, and I was wondering if it's possible to make logged out users use `Site 1` and logged in users to use `Site 2`?

This will be on the same domain by the way.

Comment: Same domain but different subdomain? Like `site1.mydomain.com` and `site2.mydomain.com`?

Comment: Did I already answer you in the EE forums? Why use MSM for this when you could do it in one site using template permissions?